# Solving a ordinary differential equation order 2

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

I have the following differential equation

$$y''(t) + -2y'(t) + 5y(t) = 0$$

With the quadratic formula:

$$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

I can compute the solutions

$$a = ,1\quad b=-2,\quad c=5$$

$$\lambda_{1,2} = \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{4-4(1\cdot 5)}}{2} = 1 \pm \frac{\sqrt{-15}}{2} = 1 \pm i(\frac{\sqrt{15}}{2})$$

However I'm given the answer: $\lambda_{1,2} = 1 \pm i2$

What am I missing?

Comment: $\sqrt{4-4\times5}=\sqrt{-16}=4i$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making a small arithmetic mistake.

$$\lambda_{1,2} = \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{4-4(1\cdot 5)}}{2} = 1 \pm \frac{\sqrt{-16}}{2} = 1 \pm i(\frac{4}{2}) = 1 \pm 2i$$

Because $4-4(1\cdot 5) = 4-20 = -16$